# Regarding having multiple JAVA_HOME on the same machine

Tags: java

I want to know whether we can have multiple JAVA_HOME on the same machine. If so, what are the steps to be followed to have multiple JAVA_HOME..? please help me with the answer...

Comment: You can install multiple versions of JDK on the same machine. The JAVA_HOME is used to point to one of them.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can try it to wrap your program into a shell script or batch file and using `SET JAVA_HOME_LOCAL`

Comment: The **real** question is why do you think that you need multiple JAVA_HOME on the same machine?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` no longer is the primary key, environment variable. With a **maven** build you can use a _profile_ (in the user's settings.xml). Other build systems the same.

Comment: You can't, you could use sdkman and enable it's auto-env feature.

Comment: Sorry i dint get my proper answer

Comment: I want steps to create multiple JAVA_HOME for multiple versions of JDK, like JAVA7_HOME and JAVA8_HOME...like this and i want to know which version is currently running..?

Comment: And also i want to point respective JAVAX_HOME for respective programs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jenv, with the export plugin enabled to change the java version and JAVA_HOME like

Configure global version

```
$ jenv global openjdk64-11.0.8
```

Configure local version (per directory)

```
$ jenv local openjdk64-11.0.8
```

Configure shell instance version

```
$ jenv shell openjdk64-11.0.8
```

To make sure JAVA_HOME is set, make sure to enable the export plugin:

```
jenv enable-plugin export
exec $SHELL -l
```

further information at https://www.jenv.be/

Comment: I want steps to create multiple JAVA_HOME for multiple versions of JDK, like JAVA7_HOME and JAVA8_HOME...like this and i want to know which version is currently running..?

Comment: if an program is under folder for example /usr/local/myprogram with jenv can use the command local setting the java needed for the program in that folder you with have the JAVA_HOME and the java version that you choose with the local command

Comment: There is also a `jenv` for Windows, installable via `scoop install jenv` if you added the scoop `extras` bucket: https://github.com/FelixSelter/JEnv-for-Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a different version of Java for different projects you will need to specify it in the project. The JAVA_HOME can only be one version.

Comment: Thank you..but I want steps to create multiple JAVA_HOME for multiple versions of JDK, like JAVA7_HOME and JAVA8_HOME...like this and i want to know which version is currently running..?

Comment: Only JAVA_HOME will be detected by programs so JAVA8_HOME etc will only be available to you.

Comment: sorry i dint get u..? U mean we cannot have multiple JAVA_HOME..?

Comment: So we cannot have customized JAVA_HOME..?

Comment: Basically you can not have multiple java homes because they wont be treated like the actual JAVA_HOME. However you can set environmental variables to point to your different java versions which you can assign manually in your projects. 
To check with java version is currently running try `java --version` in the console

Comment: So, how can I set environmental variables to point to different java versions which I can assign manually in my project..? Please help me with steps..? So that it will be very much helpful.

Comment: Hit Windows + R -> run `sysdm.cpl` -> go to the advanced tab -> click on the button `Environment Variables...`. Here you can see 2 tables click at the `System Variables` table `new` -> enter the name and provide the directory path to the java version.

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu, it works for me:

step 1: install muti version java.

step 2: example, I run muti java with maven.

- edit file barchrc:

  `vim ~/.bashrc`
- add new line:

  `JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/openjdk/jdk-15`

  `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nodejs/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin` 

  `export JAVA_HOME`  

  `alias mvn8="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_261 && mvn"`   
  `alias mvn11="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 && mvn"`  

  `alias mvn15="JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/openjdk/jdk-15 && mvn"`
- after, source file brach:

  `source ~/.bashrc`
- run test.`mvn8 clean compile` or `mvn11 clean compile`

[image]

Comment: Yahh but how to run on windows..? I want steps to create multiple JAVA_HOME for multiple versions of JDK, like JAVA7_HOME and JAVA8_HOME...like this and i want to know which version is currently running..?